# REGEX input validation

Tags: regex

I am trying to put together REGEX expression to validate the following format:

```
"XXX/XXX","XXX/XXX","XXX/XXX"
```

where `X` could be either a letter, a number, or dash or underscore. What i got so far is

```
"(.*?)(\/)(.*?)"(?:,|$)/g
```

but it does not seem to work

Update: there could be any number of "XXX/XXX" strings, comma-separated, not just 3

Comment: Is there something wrong with the provided answers?

Answer (score 1):

you can try the following regex:

```
"([\w-]+)\/([\w-]+)"
```

Edit: regex explained:

- `([\w-]+)` in the square brackets we say we want to match `\w`: matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). After this, we have "`-`", which just adds literally the symbol "`-`" to the matching symbols.
- "`+`" says we want one or more symbols from the previous block: `[\w-]`
- `\/` matches the symbol "`/`" directly. It should be escaped in the regex, that's why it is preceded by "`\`"
- `([\w-]+)` exactly like point 1, matches the same thing since the two parts are identical.
- `()` - those brackets mark capturing group, which you can later use in your code to get the value it surrounds and matches.
  Example:

Full match: `1X-/-XX`

Group 1: `1X-`

Group 2: `-XX`

Here is a demo with the matching cases - [**click**](https://regex101.com/r/2BRMNu/4). If this doesn't do the trick, let me know in the comments.

Comment: what about double-quotes?

Comment: I didn't understood you need them, edited now, take a look. The link with the example matches is also added. With examples provided from your comments below :) Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
"[-\w]+/[-\w]+"(?:,"[-\w]+/[-\w]+")*
```

**Explanation:**

```
"           # quote
[-\w]+      # 1 or more hyphen or word character [a-zA-0-9_]
/           # a slash
[-\w]+      # 1 or more hyphen or word character [a-zA-0-9_]
"           # quote
(?:         # non capture group
  ,         # a comma
  "         # quote
  [-\w]+    # 1 or more hyphen or word character [a-zA-0-9_]
  /         # a slash
  [-\w]+    # 1 or more hyphen or word character [a-zA-0-9_]
  "         # quote
)*          # end group, may appear 0 or more times
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kh1nzW/1)

Comment: Forgot the double quotes to match.

Comment: @sp00m: Good catch, fixed.

Comment: I tried this "test/test2","test3/test4","test4/test5" and it failed

Comment: oh, forgot to mention that there could be any number of comma-separated strings on type "XXX/XXX"

Comment: @CodingDuchess: Change the regex delimiter to other character than `/` or escape the slash in the regex: `\/`

Comment: @CodingDuchess: If you have any number of `xxx/xxx`, change `{2}` with `*`

Comment: @Toto, like this? "[-\w]+\/[-\w]+(?:,[-\w]+\/[-\w]+){*}

Comment: @CodingDuchess
 Where is the regex used? Tool/programming language? Remove braces from around `*`

Comment: @Toto, I added `\` to escape forward slash and it matched but then it also returns a match when only one of the xxx/xxx is wrapped in double quotes. I need each pattern to contain double quotes

Comment: @CodingDuchess: I guess you need to add anchors, add `^` at the beginning of the regex and `$` at the end. If iy doesn't work, edit your question and show real test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we would be starting with a simple expression with quantifiers:

```
("[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+")(,|$)
```

where we collect our desired three chars in a char class, followed by slash and at the end we would add an optional `,`.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3aQR27/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: I plugged in to your demo my string - `"test/test2","test3/test4","test4/test5"` and it showed no matches

Comment: yes, could be any number of chanracters but each "Xxxxxxx/xxxxx" string must be separated by commas